# Send Multiple Push Notifications to iOS users

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to send multiple (10 - 15) notifications to the registered iOS users at a time / instantaneously ? What are the limitations for iOS Push Notifications ?

Comment: Open secured socket with APNS and create one packet with notifications for 10-15 devices and send it. No problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to send multiple (10 - 15) notifications to the registered iOS users at a time / instantaneously ?**

No you can not send 10-15 notification simultaneously to same user, read more here at [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) .

> If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device or
> computer within a short period of time, the push service will send
> only the last one.

However if you intend to send push notifications to different users at same time than it should be no problem (Which i guess is what you are looking for).

**What are the limitations for iOS Push Notifications ?**

If you are not sending them simuntanously to same user than there is no limitation for APN's push notification as mentioned here .Take a look at [Push Notification Throughput and Error Checking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG44)

> There are no caps or batch size limits for using APNs. The iOS 6.1
> press release stated that APNs has sent over 4 trillion push
> notifications since it was established. It was announced at WWDC 2012
> that APNs is sending 7 billion notifications daily.
>
> If you're seeing throughput lower than 9,000 notifications per second,
> your server might benefit from improved error handling logic.
>
> Here's how to check for errors when using the enhanced notification
> format. Keep writing until a write fails. If the stream is ready for
> writing again, resend the notification and keep going. If the stream
> isn't ready for writing, see if the stream is available for reading.
>
> If it is, read everything available from the stream. If you get zero
> bytes back, the connection was closed because of an error such as an
> invalid command byte or other parsing error. If you get six bytes
> back, that's an error response that you can check for the response
> code and the ID of the notification that caused the error. You'll need
> to send every notification following that one again.
>
> Once everything has been sent, do one last check for an error
> response.
>
> It can take a while for the dropped connection to make its way from
> APNs back to your server just because of normal latency. It's possible
> to send over 500 notifications before a write fails because of the
> connection being dropped. Around 1,700 notifications writes can fail
> just because the pipe is full, so just retry in that case once the
> stream is ready for writing again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device or computer within a short period of time, the push service will send only the last one.

Here's why. The device or computer acknowledges receipt of each notification. Until the push service receives that acknowledgment, it can only assume that the device or computer has gone off-line for some reason and stores the notification in the quality of service (QoS) queue for future redelivery. The round-trip network latency here is of course a major factor.

As described in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide, the QoS queue holds a single notification per app per device or computer. If the service receives another notification before the one in the queue is sent, the new notification overwrites the previous one.

All of this points out that the intent is that a notification indicates to an app that something of interest has changed on the provider, and the app should check in with the provider to get the details. Notifications should not contain data which isn't also available elsewhere, and they should also not be stateful.

Any push notification that isn't delivered immediately was queued for future redelivery because your device was not connected to the service. "Immediately" of course needs to take latency for your connection into account. Outlying cases would be beyond 60 seconds as APNs will time out at that point.

for more info click [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)